# Quarkus unit testing - How to deal with injection problems?

Tags: unit-testing, dependency-injection, mockito, quarkus

I'm trying to make unit test in quarkus for my application. I'm maybe missing something but I have a connection to database problem. For unit test, I do not need database connection but when I'm injecting my service, automatically, Quarkus try to connect to the database. How do I mock the repository inside of the service ?

Here is the error : `io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: localhost/127.0.0.1:3306`

Here is my test class:

```
@QuarkusTest
class MyTestClass {

    @InjectMock
    MerchantRepository merchantRepository;

    @Inject
    MerchantService merchantService; // Problem with this injection I think

    @Inject
    MerchantMapper merchantMapper; 

    @Test
    void testupdate()  {

        MerchantDTO merchantDTO = new MerchantDTO();
        merchantDTO.setId("id");
        merchantDTO.setSomething2("hello");
        merchantDTO.setSomething3("hello");
        merchantDTO.setSomething4("hello");
        merchantDTO.setSomething5(false);
        
        String id = "id";
        MerchantBO merchant = merchantMapper.toBOFromDTO(merchantDTO);
        MerchantBO fake = null;

        when(merchantRepository.somemethod(merchantDTO.getId())).thenReturn(Uni.createFrom().item(merchant));
        when(merchantRepository.somemethod2(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any())).thenReturn(Uni.createFrom().item(fake));
        when(merchantRepository.somemethod3(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.any())).thenReturn(Uni.createFrom().item(fake));

        assertEquals(merchantDTO, merchantService.update(id, merchantDTO).await().indefinitely());
    }

}
```

Here is my service:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MerchantService {

    @Inject
    MerchantRepository merchantRepository;

    @Inject
    MerchantMapper merchantMapper;

    ...
}
```

Do you have any idea that could help ?

I tried to to Mock the repository inside of the object of the service and that was also not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worth reading up on [Quarkus Dev Services](https://quarkus.io/guides/dev-services). For most databases, if nothing is provisioned at dev/test time, Quarkus will automatically stand up an instance of the database using testcontainers.

This is usually much more satisfactory than a mock, because it saves a bunch of work writing mocks, and the behaviour will be closer to reality. It looks like you're using MariaDB or MySQL, is that right? There is a Quarkus Dev Service for MariaDB, so I'd suggest checking your Quarkus `application.properties` and making sure you only have a URL/connection properties set for `%prod`.

Comment: You answer is really helpfull, I understand that Quarkus help us to make integration test rather than unit test. But that not solved my problem, and so I'm still not understanding why this code doesn't work as I follow the tutorial made by Quarkus.